# Quotient by augmentation ideal

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, group-actions

Let $p$ be a prime number. Denote by $\mathbb{Z}_p$ the ring of $p$-adic integers and let $R = \mathbb{Z}_p [[X_1, \ldots, X_n]] / (f_1, \ldots, f_d)$.

Assume that a finite abelian group $G$ of order prime to $p$ act non trivially on  $R$. Let $I$ be the ideal of $R$ generated by the elements $g.r - r$ for all $g \in G$ and $r \in R$.

Consider the quotient map $f : R \to R/I$.

Is something known about the splitting of this map ? Namely, does there exist a $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebra morphism $s : R/I \to R$ such that $f \circ s = id_{R/I}$?

Comment: In an $A$-algebra $A$ is supposed to be central. How do you make $R$ a $Z_p[G]$-algebra?

Comment: That fails already for the action of the cyclic group $\{e,g\}$ of order $2$ on $\mathbb{Z}_p[[X_1,X_2]]/\langle X_1^2+X_2^2 \rangle$ by $g\cdot X_1 = X_2$ and $g\cdot X_2 = X_1$, with $p$ prime to $2$.  The quotient is $\mathbb{Z}_p[[X]]/\langle X^2 \rangle$.  The quotient algebra contains nonzero nilpotent elements, e.g., $X$, yet the original algebra $\mathbb{Z}_p[[X_1,X_2]]/\langle X_1^2+X_2^2\rangle$ contains only zero as a nilpotent element.  Thus, there cannot exist a splitting $s$.